# how to remove selected oval item color in BottomBar jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I want to remove the blue oval color behind the selected item.
How can I do that?

```
 NavigationBarItem(
        selected = selected,
        onClick = onClick,
        icon = if (selected) selectedIcon else icon,
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        label = label,
        alwaysShowLabel = alwaysShowLabel,
        colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
            selectedIconColor = AppDefaults.navigationSelectedItemColor(),
            unselectedIconColor = AppDefaults.navigationContentColor(),
            selectedTextColor = AppDefaults.navigationSelectedItemColor(),
            unselectedTextColor = AppDefaults.navigationContentColor(),
            indicatorColor = AppDefaults.navigationIndicatorColor()
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `indicatorColor = Color.Transparent`?

Comment: @JanBína Yes, It changes to black

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The color of the indicator is defined by the **`indicatorColor`** attribute in the `NavigationBarItem`.
To remove it you have to apply the same `containerColor` used by the `NavigationBar`.

If you are using the default (`containerColor` = `surface` color) you have to calculate the surface tonal color at different elevation applied to the `containerColor`.

Something like:

```
NavigationBarItem(
    icon = { androidx.compose.material3.Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
    label = { androidx.compose.material3.Text(item) },
    selected = selectedItem == index,
    onClick = { selectedItem = index },
    colors = androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItemDefaults
        .colors(
            selectedIconColor = Red,
            indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current) 
        )
)
```

[image]

In the other cases just use the same color:

```
NavigationBar(
    containerColor = Yellow
){

    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = { androidx.compose.material3.Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
            label = { androidx.compose.material3.Text(item) },
            selected = selectedItem == index,
            onClick = { selectedItem = index },
            colors = androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItemDefaults
                .colors(
                    selectedIconColor = Red,
                    indicatorColor = Yellow )
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove the ripple effect in this way?